# What data type is better to use for a PostgreSQL to store number with a floating point and why?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point

I have a Laravel application that needs to store minimum and maximum weight.
Currently, we are using integer values to store data but I need to modify it to store data values with a floating point.
What data type do I have to use for good accuracy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the `REAL` type should do the trick - if you're using kilos, you could have weights to the microgramme - unless you're using some fancy laboratory manipulations, that should be plenty - but weights like 4.567 kg (to the gramme) or 1234.45 kg (to the decigramme) would be fine.

From the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) (Table 8.2):

> real  4 bytes     variable-precision, inexact     6 decimal digits precision

or, if you require more precision:

> double precision  8 bytes     variable-precision, inexact     15 decimal digits precision

and also:

> The data types real and double precision are inexact,
> variable-precision numeric types. On all currently supported
> platforms, these types are implementations of IEEE Standard 754 for
> Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (single and double precision,
> respectively), to the extent that the underlying processor, operating
> system, and compiler support it.

This **should** be enough for any calculations involving weight where a couple of microgrammes here or there shouldn't really matter.

You **could** use one of the numeric types (`NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` - essentially synonyms)

> numeric   variable    user-specified precision, exact     up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point

However, there is a (probably unnecessary) overhead associated with these:

> However, calculations on numeric values are very slow compared to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the next section.

The upside of `NUMERIC` (or `DECIMAL`) is that:

> The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits.
> It is especially recommended for storing monetary amounts and other
> quantities where exactness is required. Calculations with numeric
> values yield exact results where possible, e.g., addition,
> subtraction, multiplication.

Obviously, your choice will depend on your (and/or your stakeholders') requirements - for weights, I recommend `REAL`.

One final idea would be to store weights as `INTEGERS` but in grammes (or mg or µg) depending on your requirements if computational power (essentially system RAM) is an issue - but I would still recommend one of the floating-point types.

- If you are interesting in pursuing this further, then you could take a look at the site recommended in a [different answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/325547/34007) to your question (thanks to the anonymous responder). That site is [`What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](https://floating-point-gui.de/) and links therein.
- A briefer explanation can be found [`here`](https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html) on the (excellent) SQLite site.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your requirements regarding correctness for math operations. Floating point values are approximate values: what you store might not be what you retrieve. For more details see [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de)

If correctness is important use `numeric`. If performance on millions or hundreds of millions of rows is more important then use a floating point type. - [user1822](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)